# How to bind a single property to the selection of two Controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have two DataGrids filled with separate collections of objects of the same type. In my ViewModel I have one property "CurrentObject" that I want to bind to the currently selected object.

That means that if I select a row in DataGrid A the CurrentObject holds the selected Item of DataGrid A and the if i select a row in DataGrid B the CurrentObject holds the selected Item of DataGrid B.

In both DataGrids I've done the binding like this:

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CurrentObject}">
```

It only works as expected when I change the selection within one DataGrid. If I select a already selected row the CurrentObject property isn't updated and still references to the object from the other DataGrid. I guess it's because the SelectionChanged event isn't fired then

Comment: Have you looked at MultiBinding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Isn't MultiBinding for binding multiple properties to a single control. I need it vice versa. Please tell me if I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: you mean CurrentObject only changed when you change selecteditem in DataGridA to DataGridB? it will not change when you change selecteditem in one DataGrid?

Comment: Your use-case is peculiar - you want the VM.CurrentObject to be updated with the selected item of the grid with most recent focus. This looks like you'll need to wire up some Click Or ItemSelected code-behind type handlers. Typically your PropertyChange handlers won't fire if the value is the same - e.g. you click on a grid item which is already selected, SelectedItem won't change. Hence no updates.

Comment: You're right. It's indeed peculiar, but in my case it's necessary. Imagine a common operation (e.g. Edit Item) for Objects in multiple DataGrids. Instead of providing the operation for each DataGrid with multiple "Edit Item" Buttons I better bind the focused selection to a single property and also provide only a single Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rang also had the idea to use Interaction Triggers to avoid code behind. Looks like we had the same idea at the same time. His approach is to handle the LostFocus event in an extra view models method, mine is to handle the GotFocus with binding. I think it's a personally preference which way to go. For the sake of completeness:

```
<iy:Interaction.Triggers>
    <iy:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <is:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext}" 
                                 PropertyName="CurrentObject" 
                                 Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedValue}" />
    </iy:EventTrigger>
</iy:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Since the Binding is only updated when the selection is changed within a single control, I additionally change the property when the DataGrid got the focus

Comment: I received a downvote. Please tell me what's wrong with my answer, since I still like my appraoch the most

Answer (score 2):

Clear SelectedItem in DataGrid's LostFocus Event:

example:

```
 private void dg1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        dg1.SelectedItem = null;
 }

 private void dg2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        dg2.SelectedItem = null;
 }
```

because if you don't clear SelectedItem when the DataGrid lostfocus, the DataGrid will still remember SelectedItem , and if you select this item again, the SelectionChanged event will not fire.

mvvm example:

```
 public void dg1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if(dg != null)
        {
            dg.SelectedItem = null;
        }

    }

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="dg1_LostFocus" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to strictly avoid Code Behind, but you made me thinking about handling focus changed events

Comment: of couse you can avoid Code Behind, use `i:Interaction ei:CallMethodAction`  or others instead if you use mvvm.

Comment: Looks like we both had the same idea at the same time ;-)

Comment: One problem I see here: When I want to call an operation on the selected item I most likely will lose the DataGrids focus (e.g. when clicking a button) and then my SelectedItem is null

Comment: @mamuesstack yes, it is a problem

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Maybe handling GotFocus is the better way here. Do you agree?

Comment: @mamuesstack yes,but you may design a better logic in GotFocus event.good luck~

Answer (score 0):

I can't clearly tell whether you're using events or bindings, but I'll suppose you do it the binding way. In that case, try setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes I do the binding way. I already use synchronization, doesn't work for me

Comment: In that case, you don't need any triggers or anything else, really. Just follow the link in my Answer and you will see that WPF manages the double selection by itself...

Comment: Sebastian, I got your point. But since the ItemsSource are two separate collections the synchronization can't work, can it?

Comment: absolutely no problem ;-)